# Unresolved inclusion: <boost/python.hpp> in Eclipse

Tags: boost-python

I have installed Boost Python in `C:\boost` in which the installation was run from `C:\Program Files\boost_1_65_1` as the root directory.

```
|C:\
|--|boost
|--|--|bin
|--|--|share

|C:\
|--|Program Files
|--|--|boost_1_65_1
```

`C:\MinGW\bin` has been added to system's PATH. In Eclipse, the `#include <boost/python.hpp>` or anything relating to `<boost\[directory]>` keeps returning 'Unresolved inclusion' error.

I have added C:\MinGW\bin to system's 'Path'. In Eclipse I added the following to  GNU C++ 'Include directories' in 'Paths and Symbols':

```
C:\boost
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_65_1\libs
C:\Program Files\boost\boost_!_65_1\boost
C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++
```

What are the settings that need to be edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bjam --debug-configuration` has to be run from the root folder

> C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_65_1

At the end of the compilation, go to

> Project Properties > C/C+ Build

and add the links to the compiler include paths (in my case it was Cross G++ Compiler > Include). The boost library should now be accessible from `#include <boost/whatever>`.